# antlr4 c++ runtime not compiling using conan package manager

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr4, conan

I'm trying to create a simple application that uses antlr4 c++ runtime to parse Java source files. However, I could not compile it due to problems with conan package manager.

I'm following antlr recommendation to use conan package manager.

My `CMakeLists.txt` file content is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(JavaParserCppRuntime)

find_package(antlr4-runtime REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} antlr4-runtime)
```

My `conanfile.txt` content is:

```
[requires]
antlr4-cppruntime/4.13.0

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

The root of my project is the folder conan-pkg-based, and the directory structure is on the following image.
[Project directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB7BC.png)

I executed the following commands in terminal with success (as recommended in [conan documentation](https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html)):

```
conan profile detect
conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

However, when I try to execute the last command `cmake --build .`, I get the following error:

```
<...>/conan-pkg-based/src/main.cpp:17:10: fatal error: antlr4-runtime.h: No such file or directory
   17 | #include "antlr4-runtime.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/JavaParserCppRuntime.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/JavaParserCppRuntime.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/JavaParserCppRuntime.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

The `main.cpp` file content is:

```
/* Copyright (c) 2012-2017 The ANTLR Project. All rights reserved.
 * Use of this file is governed by the BSD 3-clause license that
 * can be found in the LICENSE.txt file in the project root.
 */

//
//  main.cpp
//  antlr4-cpp-demo
//
//  Created by Mike Lischke on 13.03.16.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include "antlr4-runtime.h"
#include "JavaLexer.h"
#include "JavaParser.h"

// using namespace antlrcpptest;
using namespace antlr4;

void parse_file(char* file_path)
{
  std::ifstream file(file_path); // Open the file for reading

  if (file.is_open()) { // Check if the file was successfully opened
      std::string line;
      while (std::getline(file, line)) { // Read the file line by line
          std::cout << line << std::endl; // Print each line
      }

      ANTLRInputStream input(line);
      JavaLexer lexer(&input);
      CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);

      tokens.fill();
      for (auto token : tokens.getTokens()) {
        std::cout << token->toString() << std::endl;
      }

      JavaParser parser(&tokens);
      tree::ParseTree* tree = parser.compilationUnit();

      std::cout << tree->toStringTree() << std::endl << std::endl;

      file.close(); // Close the file when done reading
  } else {
      std::cout << "Failed to open the file." << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  parse_file(argv[0]);
  parse_file(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

The error clearly says that when the cmake tries to compile the main.cpp it cannot find the `"antlr4-runtime.h"` header. But that header should be provided by conan.

Comment: This sounds more like a troubleshooting, I'd recommend filing a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues for support, adding the above details plus the full output of the executed commands. (I find some small inconsistencies in the paths in the commands, could be related, but this kind of thing is better discussed in Github)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @drodri , just opened a bug issue: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/14097